# WebSphere Application Server JVM arguments not being read properly

Tags: java, jvm, noclassdeffounderror, websphere-7, jvm-arguments

We are using WebSphere 7- Application server for deploying project and this application server is given simple JVM arguments like this,

```
–Dsecurityresource=/web/sharedLibraries/security_config.xml -DConfig=/web/properties/Config.ini
```

But when tried to start the application server, a native error (native_stderr.log) is thrown as this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<verbosegc version="GA24_Java6_SR15_20131016_1337_B170922_CMPRSS">

<initialized>
  <attribute name="gcPolicy" value="-Xgcpolicy:optthruput" />
  <attribute name="maxHeapSize" value="0x100000000" />
  <attribute name="initialHeapSize" value="0xc0000000" />
  <attribute name="compressedRefs" value="true" />
  <attribute name="compressedRefsDisplacement" value="0x0" />
  <attribute name="compressedRefsShift" value="0x3" />
  <attribute name="pageSize" value="0x10000" />
  <attribute name="requestedPageSize" value="0x10000" />
</initialized>

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Dsecurityresource=.web.sharedLibraries.security-config.xml
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Dsecurityresource=.web.sharedLibraries.FalconCluster.security-config.xml
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:677)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
</verbosegc>
Could not find the main class: Dsecurityresource=/web/sharedLibraries/security-config.xml.  Program will exit.
```

The JVM arguments are given at the following location in WebSphere.

```
Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name >Java and process management > Process definition > Java virtual machine and in Generic JVM arguments
```

its strange as it is throwing NoClassDefFoundError.

or is there any other configuration in Websphere that might be causing this problem?

Note : files and path provided in the JVM arguments exists and has read and execute permissions

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the NoClassDefFoundError I think you have not mentioned the arguments as JVM arguments. Its rather parsed as class name

Comment: @Neeraj: It is passed as JVM arguments (edited the post). But some how it is been pasrsing as class name. That has been the mystery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Where are you setting these parameters?
You should set them via admin console:
`Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name`. 
Then, click `Java and process management > Process definition > Java virtual machine`

And either put them in the:

- `Generic JVM arguments` using `-Dparameter=value`
- or `Custom Properties` defining parameter as name and value as value

UPDATE
When I've pasted your variables, it contained following invisible chars instead of -D and got the same exception:

```
â€“Dsecurityresource
```

However when I went to :

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\profiles\AppSrv1\config\cells\cellName\nodes\nodeBame\servers\server1
```

and manually fixed entry in the `server.xml` file, server started correctly.

```
 <jvmEntries xmi:id="JavaVirtualMachine_1183121908656" .... genericJvmArguments="-Xquickstart -Dsecurityresource=/web/sharedLibraries/security_config.xml -DConfig=/web/properties/Config.ini" ...>
```

So please open that file with text editor and fix the `-` char before first `D`.

Comment: Yes, Parameters are set at the right location as you said
Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name >Java and process management > Process definition > Java virtual machine and in Generic JVM arguments.

sorry i forgot to mention that earlier.

Comment: Since it tells about java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Dsecurityresource=.web.sharedLibraries.security-config.xml I'm guessing that there is hidden \n after that paramter. Try to copy these params to plain text editor and back, or clean and type them manually.

Comment: no \n characters. All parameters are fine. But still the same issue.

Comment: @Rajath Updated answer. Probably found your issue.

Comment: Am late on reply but thanks a lot. It worked great.
If you could help me with my other issues in WAS. It would be really great. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721588/ibm-websphere-j2ca0145w-unable-to-start-resourceadapter-due-to-the-following

Comment: After adding arguments as we discussed here, then if I restart the server, these arguments are cleaned up. so ending up without having arguments. May I know the reason for this?

Comment: @VenkataRamireddyCH Please create new question specifying your environment, version and problem in more details. You should add arguments via admin console not directly by editing file, as it might be overwritten in ND cell during synchronization.

Comment: I came here for removing a similar issue but I located the file from the answer. Thanks guys