# IBM Websphere : J2CA0145W: Unable to start ResourceAdapter

Tags: java, websphere-7, jca

I am trying to deploy an application on WebSphere 7.0 and the Resource adapter is not getting started. What could be the reason for this. Is the resource adapter not accessible by the application being deployed? or is there a WAS configuration that needs to be set right?

The file log4j.properties do exist and have proper permissions.

The error message is

```
O log4j: Trying to find [/web/properties/Cluster/log4j.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
[9/8/14 10:16:04:703 BST] 00000027 SystemOut     O log4j: Could not find resource: [/web/properties/Cluster/log4j.properties].
[9/8/14 10:16:04:712 BST] 00000027 RALifeCycleMa E   J2CA0128E: An Exception occurred while trying to start ResourceAdapter cells/mdecell643/applications/frmc-mq-ear.ear/deployments/frmc-mq-ear/deployment.xml#J2CResourceAdapter_1409904209419. The exception is: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: Error while initializing workflow engine
        at com.amd.ps.frd.frmc.ra.NextCaseResourceAdapterImpl.start(NextCaseResourceAdapterImpl.java:50)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RAWrapperImpl.startRA(RAWrapperImpl.java:752)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.startRA(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:1140)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.resourceProviderEvent(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:859)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl$ResourceEventListenerFilterProxy.resourceProviderEvent(ResourceMgrImpl.java:2139)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl.notifyResourceEventListeners(ResourceMgrImpl.java:1605)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl.installResourceProvider(ResourceMgrImpl.java:1494)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl.installResourceProvider(ResourceMgrImpl.java:1445)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.start(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:657)



    [9/8/14 10:16:04:716 BST] 00000027 RALifeCycleMa E   J2CA0145W: Unable to start ResourceAdapter due to the following exception: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: Error while initializing workflow engine
        at com.amd.ps.frd.frmc.ra.NextCaseResourceAdapterImpl.start(NextCaseResourceAdapterImpl.java:50)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RAWrapperImpl.startRA(RAWrapperImpl.java:752)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.startRA(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:1140)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.resourceProviderEvent(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:859)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl$ResourceEventListenerFilterProxy.resourceProviderEvent(ResourceMgrImpl.java:2139)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl.notifyResourceEventListeners(ResourceMgrImpl.java:1605)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl.installResourceProvider(ResourceMgrImpl.java:1494)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl.installResourceProvider(ResourceMgrImpl.java:1445)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.start(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:657)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1146)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:611)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:759)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1291)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5395)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5483)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1296)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2068)

    .
    [9/8/14 10:16:04:719 BST] 00000027 RALifeCycleMa E   J2CA0143E: Embedded ResourceAdapter initialization failed due to Exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: Unable to start ResourceAdapter due to exception
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.resourceProviderEvent(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:874)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl$ResourceEventListenerFilterProxy.resourceProviderEvent(ResourceMgrImpl.java:2139)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl.notifyResourceEventListeners(ResourceMgrImpl.java:1605)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl.installResourceProvider(ResourceMgrImpl.java:1494)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ResourceMgrImpl.installResourceProvider(ResourceMgrImpl.java:1445)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.start(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:657)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1146)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:611)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:759)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1291)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5395)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5483)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1296)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2068)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:332)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This appears to be an error thrown by the `com.amd.ps.frd.frmc.ra.NextCaseResourceAdapterImpl.start` method, which is not part of WebSphere Application Server. If that's your RA, you'll have to investigate the source. If not, you'll have to get support from them (I don't recognize the package, so I don't know if there is an appropriate stackoverflow tag).

Comment: Thank you. Cause of this was resource adapters were wrongly configured so it could not start up.